# How can I run a gem's tests when using bundler

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I have a private gem (built with jeweler) hosted on Github. I run unit tests before I commit but I'd like to test everything works when I use bundler from the end-user side.

So far I've just been creating a test environment with two files:

**Gemfile:**

```
gem 'my_gem', :git => 'git@github.com:my_repo/my_gem.git'
```

**main.rb:**

```
require "rubygems"
require "bundler/setup"
require "my_gem"

# Some code calling arbitrary methods from my gem
```

It seems like there's probably a way for me to run the unit tests built in to the gem.

Answer (score 1):

Bundler supports the use of gemspecs for development.  You can change your gemfile to the following:

```
source "http://www.rubygems.org"

gemspec
```

This will allow you to access all the gems you would need as a client of the gem you're building.  Then in your test file you can just:

```
require "my_gem"
```

You can find more information in [Yehuda's post](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/12/16/clarifying-the-roles-of-the-gemspec-and-gemfile/).